# Get HTML content of webpage with webview

Tags: react-native

I want to get html code with webview in react native my current code only can call alert function after its injected. i want to get a specific div html content.

```
  const jsCode = "window.postMessage(alert(document.getElementById('result')))"

<WebView 
            style={{width:Dimensions.get('window').width,height:Dimensions.get('window').height}}
            javaScriptEnabled ={true}
             injectedJavaScript={jsCode} 
            source={{uri: this.state.uri}}
      />
```

Answer (score 7):

`window.postMessage` causes the `WebView.onMessage`-handler to get called with the data.

So this should work:

```
const jsCode = "window.postMessage(document.getElementById('gb-main').innerHTML)"

<WebView
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
  source={{uri: 'http://www.google.com/'}}
  onMessage={event => console.log('Received: ', event.nativeEvent.data)}
/>
```

Comment: @berkintatlisu On android the webview runs the injected script before the postMessage handler is attached to the window. Fixable by e.g. using a timeout to wait for the postMessage handler, something like this: `const jsCode = "window.waitForBridge = function(fn) { return (window.postMessage.length === 1) ? fn() : setTimeout(function() { window.waitForBridge(fn) }, 5) }; window.waitForBridge(function() { window.postMessage(document.getElementById('gb-main').innerHTML) });"`

Comment: great! you saved my day

Comment: If you use **react-native-webview** package, then try this:

`window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage`